# How to use component in slot for component testing with Cypress and Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, cypress

I need to import a component in slot with Cypress component Testing using Vue.

Documentation say that for slots :

```
import DefaultSlot from './DefaultSlot.vue'

describe('<DefaultSlot />', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    cy.mount(DefaultSlot, {
      slots: {
        default: 'Hello there!',
      },
    })
    cy.get('div.content').should('have.text', 'Hello there!')
  })
})
```

I want to do like this :

```
<DefaultSlot>
 <AnotherSlot />
</DefaultSlot>
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve my question, I've imported component using components options like :

```
import DefaultSlot from './DefaultSlot.vue'
import AnotherSlot from './AnotherSlot.vue'

describe('<DefaultSlot />', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    cy.mount(DefaultSlot, {
      components: {
        AnotherSlot
      }
      slots: {
        default: '<AnotherSlot label="my label" />',
      },
    })
    cy.get('div.content').should('have.text', 'Hello there!')
  })
})
```